# Unable to store stripe webhook data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I have set webhook in my `stripe` account and while doing test webhook from stripe dashboard, I am getting success result from the stripe. I can see the response in preview.

But while doing that thing from the browser and hitting the same webhook url, I am getting nothing in my response .

Here is the code that I am using to make it work.

=======================================

```
include('config.php');

function searchArrayValueByKey(array $array, $search) 
{
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $key => $value) 
    {
        if ($search === $key)
        return $value;
    }
    return false;
}

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("Stripe Key");

// This function is leveraged to search through the JSON for specific values

$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");         
// this gets the POST data provided when the webhook pings this page
$event_json = json_decode($input, TRUE);    
// decode the JSON, and TRUE turns it into a multidimensional array

if(isset($type))
{
    $type = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'customer.subscription.updated'); 
}
else
{
    $type = "";
}
// Check the type of event sent from Stripe.com - example "charge.succeeded"

switch ($type) 
{                                   
    // depending on the event fired by Stripe, do something different. 
    case "account.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "balance.available":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.captured":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.refunded":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.succeeded":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.failed":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.dispute.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.dispute.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.dispute.closed":
        // do something
        break;
    case "coupon.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "coupon.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.card.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.card.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.card.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.discount.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.discount.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.discount.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.subscription.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.subscription.updated":

        $id = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'id'); 
        $customer_id = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'customer'); 
        $created = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'created'); 
        $subscription = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'subscription'); 
        $period_start = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'period_start'); 
        $period_end = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'period_end'); 

        $insert_into = mysqli_query($conn,"insert into ext_payment_data set
                                        subscription = '".$subscription."',
                                        add_date = '".$created."',
                                        subscr_id = '".$subscription."',
                                        subscribe_from_date = '".$period_start."',
                                        subscribe_to_date = '".$period_end."',
                                        response = '".json_encode($event_json)."'
            ");     

        break;
    case "customer.subscription.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.subscription.trial_will_end":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoice.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoice.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoice.payment_succeeded":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoice.payment_failed":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoiceitem.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoiceitem.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoiceitem.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "plan.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "plan.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "plan.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "transfer.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "transfer.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "transfer.paid":
        // do something
        break;
    case "transfer.failed":
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        echo "Error";

}

$myfile = fopen("auto_response.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
file_put_contents('auto_response.txt', print_r($event_json,true),FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
fclose($myfile);
```

==================

Here while writing the response in `auto_response.txt` file, I am able to store that data in the file, but while storing that data in database I am getting nothing.

So is any one have any solution for that, as I am not able to store the stripe response in my mysql database.

Comment: `But while doing that thing from the browser and hitting the same webhook url` - what do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean to say that while hitting the webhook url from the browser there no data will be store in database, as you can see there i have implemented sql query inside switch case

Comment: Why would you expect there be any data in that case? It's a POST endpoint, if you're hitting it from a browser there will be no request body. `php://input` is empty for a GET request..

Comment: Ok so can you provide me any solution that how can i get the data and store it in database.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you do this:

```
insert into ext_payment_data set
```

The `set` operator is for updates, not inserts.

The query needs to change a little:

```
"insert into ext_payment_data (
    subscription, 
    add_date, 
    subscr_id, 
    subscribe_from_date, 
    subscribe_to_date, 
    response
 ) values (
    '".$subscription."', 
    '".$created."', 
    '".$subscription."', 
    '".$period_start."', 
    '".$period_end."', 
    '".json_encode($event_json)."'
 )
"
```

NOTE that, depending on how you handle your user input, using a prepared statement is safer to prevent [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: This is the another syntax of mysql database query and i have used it so many times, Its working perfect everywhere. Issue is i am not getting any response in event_json variable and i am not able to print the data that i am getting in it.

Comment: Oh okay, didn't even know that existed. Learn something everyday, right?